# PHP INI Use Variable or Relative Path for Directive Values

Tags: php

In my php.ini file I currently have something like this:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/home/portaj/devel/dd/crosslight/var/tmp/upload/"
```

But I would like to be able to specify all of the paths relative to either a ROOT variable or something.

Something like this:

```
upload_tmp_dir = ROOT + "var/tmp/upload/"
```

Is something like this possible?  I can't seem to find it on php.net, or via Google searching.  So, I figured it either exists and I am looking at the problem wrong, or, it doesn't exist. :P

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this configuration directive changeable in `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` which means it can only be set in the `php.ini` file or the `httpd.conf` file. For reference view http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir and this rejected bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9866